# Different exceptions for pop from empty sets and lists?

Tags: python, list, exception, set

Why do empty sets and lists raise different exceptions when you call .pop()?

```
>>> l = []
>>> l.pop()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#15>", line 1, in <module>
    l.pop()
IndexError: pop from empty list
>>> l = set()
>>> l.pop()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    l.pop()
KeyError: 'pop from an empty set'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `sets` are a lot like `dict`s but without the values:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d.pop('foo')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'pop(): dictionary is empty'
```

Both dictionaries and sets are not indexed, like lists are, so an `IndexError` makes no sense here. But *like* dictionaries, there is only ever one value of each 'key' in the set.

Comment: Getting a `KeyError` when the key provided to `dict.pop({key value})` doesn't exist, regardless of whether or not the dictionary is empty, certainly makes sense, but not so much with `set.pop()` which does not accept one as an argument. My guess is that it's to be compatible with the `Set` class in the [`sets`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) module introduced in Python 2.3 which were implemented using dictionaries according to the documentation.

Comment: @martineau: `.remove()` also raises a `KeyError`. According to [this commit](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3086620db46b/Objects/setobject.c) it was modeled after `dict.pop()` *explicitly*.

Comment: `Set.remove()` in the `sets` module did this so it likely just backwards compatibility again, _and_ like `dict.pop()` -- but unlike both `Set.pop()` and `set.pop()` -- the `set.remove()` method also takes an argument (although it's called _elem_ in the documentation, not _key_). All of which make me doubt that the commit comment could be considered strong evidence.

Answer (score 7):

Lists are ordered sequences, accessed by index; sets are unordered and non-sequential, accessed by key, hence the error messages.